# Getting the list of compressors in c#

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, image-compression

I want to get the list of registered compressors in the system using c#.

I have found [ICCompressorChoose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742967(v=vs.85).aspx) function which will be helpful. But it comes with a dialog box. I just need the data that contains the list of compressor. Then I will use a custom UI to display the data.

Is there any way to get the list of registered compressors?